# Find a specific character at the beginning of a .m file

Tags: regex, matlab

I am new to Matlab and I'm trying to write a program that should search for a pipe symbol,`|` before the function is declared in a .m file.

For example:

```
% |
function y = add(x,z)
    y = x+z
end
```

I have an idea on how to proceed but I'm unable to write the code for it:

1. Ask the user for the file that should be parsed
2. Open the file
3. Skip any empty lines present at the beginning of the file
4. Extract the first comment before the function declaration, proceed depending on the presence of the `|` symbol

What I've been able to put into code so far:

```
function y = filesearch()
%Ask user for file to parse
[fileName, filePath] = uiputfile('*.m','Choose file you want to parse');
% Open the file:
fid = fopen(filePath);

% Skip empty lines:
defLine = '';
while all(isspace(defLine))
    defLine = strip_comments(fgets(fid));
end
% Check for presence of |
```

As you can see I am unable to think of a line that can strip the comment(if it exists) and check for presence of a pipe symbol.

Additionally, though it **isn't a priority right now** I'd like to use this symbol at the end of each line if it satisfies certain parameters.
For example:

`Algebraic`(No | symbol at end of line)

```
R1 = 1; R2 = 2; R3 = 3;
Rs = R1 + R2 + R3;
```

`Differential`(| at the end of dydt statement)

```
% |
function dydt = vanderpoldemo(t,y,Mu)
%VANDERPOLDEMO Defines the van der Pol equation for ODEDEMO.
dydt = [y(2); Mu*(1-y(1)^2)*y(2)-y(1)]; % |
```

For the above differential case I think a **regex** would be needed (once the intial `|` is found before the function declaration) to check for the presence of a `|` at the end of a line where the declaration is not algebraic.

I would appreciate any help or advice with how to extract and check the initial comment and if, possible how can I implement my additional question where I should check if symbol exists at the end of every line.

Answer (score 1):

The following code goes through a file line by line and searches the pipe symbol in a comment. It stops after it was found:

```
fid = fopen('add.m');
% Check for presence of | in a comment
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    if strfind(tline,'%')       % find comments
        if strfind(tline,'|')   % find pipe
            disp(tline)         % do something
            break;              % stop while loop
        end
    end
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
```